# can-model cannot getting data from .json file

Tags: javascript, json, requirejs, canjs, canjs-model

I am trying to implement MVC using AMD in canjs. For that I am using requirejs.
This is my domains.json file:

```
[            
"1":{"uid":     "1","urls": "domain1.abc.com"},
"2":{"uid":    "2","urls": "domain2.abc.com"},
"3":{"uid":    "3","urls": "domain3.abc.com"}
]
```

This is my domainModel:

```
define(['can'], function(can){
  SearchModel= can.Model({
     id: 'uid',
     findAll: 'GET /domains.json'
  },{})
  return SearchModel;
})
```

This is my controller:

```
define(['can','jquery'],function(can,$){
 domainController=can.Control({defaults:{view:"../view/search.hbs" }},           
  {
    init : function(element,options){   
        this.element.html(can.view(this.options.view,{
            searchlist : this.options.search
        }))
    }
});
return domainController;
}
```

This is my main js:

```
equirejs(['can','controller/domainController','model/domainModel'],
 function(can, domainController,domainModel) {
   var Application = can.Control.extend({
    defaults :{ }
   },{  
        init: function(element,options){
         console.log('loaded');
         domainModel.findAll({}, function(domains){
            domainObject:{searchdomains : domains}
                 new domainController('#search',domainObject)
            });
        }
    })
return Application;
});
```

I am tracing out my code.I put breakpoints.On model breakpoints I am not getting values in local variables in chrome devtools.

The url property has 'undefined/{id}' value and findAll method having four properties i.e. arguments,caller,length and name having a value null, null, 0 and "" respectively

I have checked my url of model by navigating through localhost on browser and it is correct.
Then why model cannot getting the values of json file?

Comment: Remember object names cannot start with a number, so in the domains.json file, change the names from 1, 2, 3, to something like "one", "two", "three". It is ok to make a json with object names that start with integers but when you try to access these objects in js, it will not work properly. [valid JS variable names](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get an error message since your data is not what Model expects for findAll. Your JSON should be an array (or at least have a length property):

```
[
  {"uid":     "1","urls": "domain1.abc.com"},
  {"uid":    "2","urls": "domain2.abc.com"},
  {"uid":    "3","urls": "domain3.abc.com"}
]
```

You also probably want to set the `id` property in you SearchModel to `uid`:

```
define(['can'], function(can){
  SearchModel= can.Model({
     id: 'uid',
     findAll: 'GET /domains.json'
  },{})
  return SearchModel;
})
```

Comment: I already tried with array. Its not working. Is it important to set id property in model? if yes can you please tell me the reason.

Comment: Well it needs to know what the models id property is. That shouldn't be the problem though. Hat you tried `{ "data": [] }` in your JSON file? Can you see it requesting the correct file in the network tab?

Comment: thank you so much. I didn't know that "data" is a keyword which has to be used in the JSON. I was using different word. You guys are doing great work. Please keep it going!!

Comment: This might actually be a Chrome safety restriction. Thanks! And glad it worked. Feel free to drop by https://gitter.im/bitovi/canjs if you have more questions.